# Get the Value of the Checked Item/s in the CheckedListbox

Tags: mysql, vb.net, checkedlistbox

I badly need help. Just a newbie in this. I am having a hard time in getting the data from my checkedlistbox and also retrieved the checked items in the same checkedlistbox with the data coming from my database.

Here are the codes I've started with ...

Loads the data from my chosen field:

```vb
 Try
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT name from requirements"
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        For Each dRow As DataRow In dt.Rows
            CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(dRow.Item("name"))
        Next
        conn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```

I've searched this from the internet in which I'll be able to retrieve the index of the checked item/s:

```vb
Dim str1 As String = "Checked indices are: "
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To CheckedListBox1.CheckedIndices.Count - 1
    str1 = str1 & CheckedListBox1.CheckedIndices(i).ToString & ", "
Next

MsgBox(str1)
```

My question is that how will I be able to get the value of the checked item/s (the names) through the indices and save it to the database? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends on what you means by `the value of the checked item`.  You only put the name in the control so if you want the ID, you will have to look it up.

Comment: The value of the checked names on the checked listbox Sir. That's what I meant for "the value of the checked item" sorry for the confusion @Plutonix

Answer (score 0):

There is no html tag like

```
<checkbox value="5" checked>
```

if you meant just simple

```
<input id="Checkbox" type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" value="5"/>
```

then u can get the value using forms collection

```
label_Result.text = Request.Form["mycheckbox"];
```

and you will get the value 5 only if that checkbox is checked . You can add values dynamically like this

```
CheckBox2.Attributes.Add("Value", 2);
```

The "Add" method add takes two parameters. The first parameter is the name of the attribute . The second parameter is the value for this attribute.